# Docs.SO linked upvotes drowns rep report from SO answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, reputation, achievements-dialog

I noticed when an answer links to a Documentation.SO post, and that Docs.SO post gets upvoted, suddenly all rep acquired from that answer is "swallowed" by the Docs.SO linked topic in the *achievements* dropdown:

[image: +25 On Error statement]

That "On Error statement" is a Documentation.SO topic, and only really earned +5. I believe the achievements dropdown should say:

- +5 On Error statement
- +20 Is there a free utility tool or macro to auto populate line number in vba editor?

(that said, VTC's aren't piling up on that question half as fast as I'd have expected them to)

---

UPDATE: After receiving another vote, it seems the behavior is actually that the caption accompanying the +score is either the Docs.SO topic, or the SO answer, depending on whichever was last voted on. That doesn't seem right anyway.

Comment: Oh jeez... that question, that answer.... Get ready for the meta effect.

Comment: Why are you answering the question if it should be closed?

Comment: @ayhan I wrote a 4,207 character answer (52 characters of which directly answer OP's question) to *educate* the OP and anyone reading it, about why *you don't need line numbers in VBA, whatever the reason you might think you do*. In other words: for the Greater Good and whatever hope is left to Humanity. The question already had 2 other answers and 0 close votes when I got to it BTW.

Comment: It's so tentatively an x/y answer that muh fingernails are screaming in sympathy.

Comment: @Mat'sMug So you did exactly what you know is bad for the site, and did the thing that the site tries to prevent with question closure.

Comment: @Servy *there already were answers*, and *I cast the first close vote* that sent it to the close queue in the first place. And I didn't spoonfeed the OP with "use this" [link to a tool] or "try that" [here's some code] - instead I addressed the OP's *actual* problem (XY) and made the Internet a Better Place by allowing future readers to weight the other (OP-accepted) spoonfeeding answers against my "don't do that" answer. So just how bad is it?

Comment: What makes you think that someone else cannot write a better answer that addresses the *actual* problem? What makes you so special that only you should be given that privilege?

Comment: Give a man a fish and you feed his XY problem. Teach a man to fish and the problem goes away.

Comment: @ayhan because I'm a mug and this comment trail is just as off-topic as the question being discussed. This is a post about a bug in the achievements dropdown, yet people comment on whether an answer should have been posted or not on an off-topic question that nobody cared enough about to vote to close in *over 2 hours*. That tag is plagued with dupes that nobody cares to close as such - somewhere around 99% of every new VBA question is a dupe, yet high-rep users keep answering them. When I earn my gold, I'll be "special" enough to hammer them. In the meantime, one's gotta earn dat gold.

Comment: @Mat'sMug This comment trail is off-topic indeed, but it also worth noting that the majority close reason (not yours -- you cast a duplicate vote) is also wrong. That the OP there asked "Is there a macro that..." rather than "How do I..." is a(nother) XY issue, and not a reason to close.

Comment: @duplode actually if you look at the timestamps I VTC'd as stated in the "on hold" banner, and linked to the would-have-been dupe after the last close vote was in. At the end of the day, the question is closed, and it links to a similar question that *did* answer OP's question. Besides the question *as titled* was definitely asking for *that* close reason, duplicate or not.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Oh sure, the faux-auto-comment trick :) I hadn't seen the question or its title before the edits. Looking at the original question shows the vote was very reasonable indeed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next deploy.

Small change, but in a very particular (and finicky) place.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! No clue what `i` and `rh` stand for though. #NamingIsHard ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug rh is probably repHistory and i should be inbox #MiniCodeReview

Comment: @Vogel612 and the code reviewer in you is fine with that? The indent level also points to it being part of some bigger scope.. feels like each parenthesized branch could be extracted into one or more smaller predicate functions. But hey, *it works*!

Comment: FWIW with the throughput probably expected of this, I daresay that even method overhead might result in unhappy sysadmins and users and more. As such I think it's an acceptable tradeoff.